# HTML Bullet Points in Columns

Tags: html

Just so I can try a few different layouts/designs etc could you please help me with how to get all the bullet points in a single column one after the other.

[image]

Please see the image above of how I want it to look. All the bullet points on one line going across the page.

Below is what I currently have and what I want to be displayed in bullet points that spread evenly across the page.

```
<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Walls-/_i.html?
_fsub=1806276619&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" 
style="color:#000000">- Wall Display Systems  

<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Windows-/_i.html?
_fsub=1806276419&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" 
style="color:#000000">- Window Display Systems

<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Ceilings-/_i.html?
_fsub=1806276519&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" 
style="color:#000000">- Ceiling Display Systems

<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Floors-/_i.html?
_fsub=1806276719&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" 
style="color:#000000">- Floor Display Systems

<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/Merchandising-
Accessories-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276819&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" 
target="_blank" style="color:#000000">- In-Store Displays

<a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/Signware-Exlusive-/_i.html?
_fsub=1806280119&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" 
style="color:#000000">- Signware Exclusive
</a></p>
```

I can do normal vertical BPs but just not in columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` to get this:

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

> Note the `margin-right` I added there.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
    <style>
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
     }

     li {
        display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Walls-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276619&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">Wall Display Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Windows-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276419&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">Window Display Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Ceilings-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276519&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">Ceiling Display Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/For-Floors-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276719&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">Floor Display Systems</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/Merchandising-Accessories-/_i.html?_fsub=1806276819&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">In-Store Displays</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stores.ebay.co.uk/Signware/Signware-Exlusive-/_i.html?_fsub=1806280119&_sid=1601798509&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322" target="_blank" style="color:#000000">Signware Exclusive</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `<li>` attribute will generate bullets, and the inline-block will make the li's lay next to each other. The `<div>`attribute make the text float in the center.